# Which owl is the source of Arima's quinque?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

Considering the confusion between the 2 owls (Yoshimura vs Eto) do we know which one Arima took this quinque from? Has he fought both? I'm not sure if a Tokyo Ghoul: re tag is worthwhile.

[image]

Comment: If not the fact, that quinque should be done with stile alive ghoul, I would suppose, that this is leftovers from Eto's kagune, which was left after battle with Kaneki during Tsukiyama operation. No better assumptions, since there were no other ghouls of SSS rate other than Eto.

Comment: @lentinant First off, the Ghoul can be dead, the Kagune Sac itself is all that is important, like most human organs, its still good after death, though how long is uncertain since its not human. Second, It cant be from Kaneki's fight against Eto, She did not leave any Kagune Sacs, just RC Cells. Third, Yoshimura is also SSS, and classified as OWL, Eto is One eyed Owl. Fourth, He did fight and win against at least one of them a long time ago, I believe Yoshimura references this when he fights Kurowa and Shinohara.

Comment: @Ryan Yoshimura references, that he lost arm to Arima, not Kakuho. Still, all "material" from Yoshimura still belongs to Aogiri, at least at the moment, when Arima faces Kaneki.

Comment: @Ryan, well, this Quinque may be done with part of actually Eto's kakuho. Kaneki was given part of Rize kakuho, and this part still works as fully functional kakuho. This means, that it is possible to take part of kakuho from ghoul without killing him (especially when we are talking about Eto, who has high regenerative abilities). Eto was imprisoned for long time in Cochlea, so it was possible for her to have operation meanwhile. Also, I can't believe she lost so easily to Fuwa, which makes me think she was weakened. But this is also completely my imagination without any proofs.

Comment: @lentinant Dont forget Ghouls can have more than one Kakuho. Jason had at least 2, Kaneki Ate one, but he had another which he used on Juzo before being killed.  Yoshimura and Eto have 6-8 according to the Wiki, and Shinohara noted Centipede had several. They of course regenerate as well, which is how they are farmed. I also highly doubt ghouls in Cochila are fed until they are full. Eto was likely Very hungry and weak when she fought Furuta.

Answer (score 1):

The Quinque you showed was taken from the body of **Yoshimura**.

Source : http://tokyoghoul.wikia.com/wiki/Owl_(Quinque)

Comment: Oddly enough, the wiki references the page in the question as evidence that it was Yoshimura. This is despite the fact that its confirmed he fought both Owls and it still could have been from either, with him not telling the whole truth so as to not yet reveal his plan. This is the best answer, if only because we have no clear explanation, just puzzle pieces that seem to match Yoshimura a bit better than Eto.